# What's the purpose of truth that can be psychosocially manipulated? When are they "science-capable"?

Tags: truth, philosophy-of-psychology

What's the purpose of truth that can be psychosocially manipulated? When are they "science-capable"?

Such as things related to e.g.

- deservingness
- personal worth
- fairness

Since it's not possible to attain consistency (consistent interpretation) in these.

---

Critique:

"Opinion-basedness" cannot be a problem, if such opinions are applied in general fact-like sense.

Or researched as "science", such as various psychological studies that e.g. mention "self-esteem".

Comment: I think you need to expand this question, unclear what exactly you are asking.

Comment: Any truth can be psychosocially manipulated, evolution and climate are hard science examples. It is not possible to attain consistency in reception of art either, should we then dispense with art? Multiple frameworks for assessing traits, even incompatible, are better than none at all. At least, people get something systematic to choose from.

Comment: Well, one possible and slightly trivial answer might be that capacity to influence is, indeed, part of what a reasonable analysis of truth ought to preserve.  This is something Foucault was quite keen to emphasise - that truth comes Regimes, just as much in the academy and in how we might wish to conceptualise a free and open media as at the hands of the despotic tyrant, and the question is really of methods and their analysis in the archaeology of ideas. But is this outside of how you're looking at it?

Comment: @PaulRoss If the ideas are manipulatable as false, then does it make sense to talk about truth? OTOH, there exists information that cannot be psychosocially manipulated, because it's possible to check, whether the truth holds. However, there are plenty of things whose observation depends on the used definition and possibly an implicit background "value choice". As an example, lets say that a CEO of a company thinks he is fair, while his employees don't think so. Is there a truth to the CEO's fairness and how is it truthfully inferable? If it cannot be, then is it meaningful?

Comment: One possible answer could also include that some philosophers consider that it's not necessary for knowledge to be consistent. Which accounts for a kind of "temporary truth" idea of truth or "useful knowledge" type of pragmatic view. Or i.e. that it's unreasonable to expect consistency as the prerequisite for truth, in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative is logical positivism and behaviorism, two thoroughly dead ends. Why do you think consistency is the be all and end all?

> “For a large class of cases of the employment of the word
> ‘meaning’—though not for all—this word can be explained in this way:
> the meaning of a word is its use in the language” Wittgenstein, PI 43

And thus language evolves along with us - the human body itself is not 'consistent', why should their noise-gestures be?

Objectivity is just reified intersubjectivity. We have no access to information that hasn't passed through a mind.

Comment: "Why do you think consistency is the be all and end all?". It's required in order to judge people consistently. If people cannot be judged consistently, then what's the purpose of any measures? Or the usage of words whose meaning depends on who uses it.

Comment: @mavavilj: And, why is that important?

Comment: It is if someone thinks of restricting free speech for example. And there are those kinds of people.

Comment: Or someone who wants to "rank" people, like educators. Or psychologists. They infer people based on what they say. If they cannot be consistent, then are their judgements meaningful? How do you judge a libel or bullying, if meaning of words is not consistent?

Comment: 'those kinds of people', meaning what? Are you talking about a way to restrict free speech in some fair or logical way..? 'based on what they say' & your problem with this is that it can be psychosocially manipulated but they act like it's not..?

Comment: Well how do you attain an observation on verbal bullying, if the meaning and intention of words is not consistent?

Comment: You judge intent. Intent is not **in** words, but in how they are used. As per courts of law, in the end it comes down to a judgement call, but we can try to have a fair and consistent process leading up to that, informed by precedent. What you call 'inconsistency' isn't a free-for-all, the new gets built on the old. Like how in science the fact knowledge is tentative isn't a free for all - we can be absolutely certain that either QM or Relativity isn't right, probably both, so we seek a framework that can be more consistent, not less. But there is no perfect understanding, or finished theory

Comment: The intent is surely influenced by the words used, because people would be bothered by "bad words" instead of "nice words". They view bad words are bad. And the words used may be one of the few ways to interpret mental state. Because one might have a similar intent and then be nice vs bully. And what dinstinguishes is the words used, but not their motive, which is hidden, the same in both cases or "tricked". What if someone's intent is to trick people into believing nice things? A hypocrite of sorts. Or what if someone says things that he/she "doesn't really mean"?

Comment: How does one infer ingenuity, if not by words and their relation? How does one infer ingenuity without words? There's no meaning w/o words.

Comment: @mavavilj: “For a large class of cases of the employment of the word ‘meaning’—though not for all—this word can be explained in this way: the meaning of a word is its use in the language” Wittgenstein, PI 43

Comment: That's naive, because it doesn't consider difference in interpretation.

Comment: .. Interpretation is exactly the point..?

Comment: And if it's not consistent, then is it truthful?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127659/discussion-between-criglcragl-and-mavavilj).